# How to avoid the below div from receiving the event?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a div called "lower", and a div called "upper". The lower div has a `dblclick` event, and the upper div is nested inside "lower" (and appears on top) of the lower div. There is no `dblclick` event on the upper div.

How can I prevent the lower div from receiving the double click event when I double click the upper div?

```
$('#lower').dblclick(function(e){ 
    alert("event occurred !");
});
```

Comment: Is "upper" maybe inside "lower"? (in the HTML DOM structure)

Comment: yes, the upper is insider the lower, in the dom.

Answer (score 2):

If as @thejh suggests #upper is inside #lower, you could try this

```
$('#upper').dblclick(function(e){ 
            e.stopPropagation();
    });
```